# Symfony 3: custom your class input field ONLY if there is an error

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Usually we can customize the attribute class of an input field from
twig with

```
{{ form_widget(form.username,{'attr':{
       'class':'input',
       'placeholder':'Write your username'
    }}) }}
```

But how to add a class depending upon the fact that this field has an error?

For example I want my input tag to have an additional class "is-danger" if there is an error encountered during submission

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by setting a variable before:

```
            {% if form_errors(form.username) is not empty %}
                    {% set class = "input is-danger" %}
                {% else %}
                    {% set class = "input" %}
                {% endif %}
                {{ form_widget(form.username,{'attr':{
                    'class':class,
                    'placeholder':'Write your username'
                }}) }}
```

It is a bit cumbersome to post all of that in the template though.

Comment: Did you try my solution with macros?  It cleans it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your workaround with a macro:

```
{% macro inputClass(field) %}
{% spaceless %}
    class="input{% if form_errors(field) is not empty %} is-danger{% endif %}"
{% endspaceless %}
{% endmacro %}
```

and then

```
{{ form_widget(form.username, {'attr': {
    'class': inputClass(form.username),
    'placeholder': 'Write your username'
}}) }}
```

If you want a more global solution you should be able to [override a form block](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html).  Or, instead of putting the attribute on the main widget, you could just customize the `form_errors()` call rather than require that class to be added to the widget itself.